# How to work with OpenSSL for Rust within a Windows development environment

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, rust, openssl, rust-cargo

I can't build my Rust project when I add an SSL dependency in my cargo file.
This isn't new to Windows, but I'd like to resolve the issue such that I can use Powershell and native Windows development to work on my Rust project.

The dependency in question is the following:

```
[dependencies.ws]
version = "0.8.0"
features = ["ssl"]
```

When I run `cargo build`, I get a lot of errors regarding SSL as I'm on Windows so let us begin debugging this step by step.

First errors:

```
PS C:\Users\sam\vcs\project> cargo build
   Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.43
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.43`
process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\sam\vcs\project\target\debug\build\openssl-sys-d964f46e4c48d206\build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_DIR
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
OPENSSL_DIR unset
note: vcpkg did not find openssl as libcrypto and libssl: Aborted because VCPKGRS_DYNAMIC is not set
note: vcpkg did not find openssl as ssleay32 and libeay32: Aborted because VCPKGRS_DYNAMIC is not set
```

Alright, lets set `OPENSSL_LIB_DIR`, `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR`, and `OPENSSL_DIR`

```
$env:OPENSSL_LIB_DIR="C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib"
$env:OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\OpenSSL-Win64\include"
$env:OPENSSL_DIR="C:\OpenSSL-Win64"
```

However, now running `cargo build` or `cargo run` actually compiles, but I don't think SSL works correctly since the code path that connects to the websocket fails with error none.

I installed the latest (1.1.0j) full (non-slim) version of OpenSSL from the following website: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

The only environment variable it had set was:

```
OPENSSL_CONF: C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
```

But I also added `C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin` to my `PATH`.

When `cargo build` actually compiled, the websocket fails with error `None`

The `on_error` block is executed on my Windows box, but my Linux machine never executes this code block.

Just so we're on the same page, this is the output of the print statement:

```
fn on_error(&mut self, err: ws::Error) {
    println!("On Error, {}", err)
}
```

None isn't a very descriptive answer. So I assumed that I just needed some certs since OpenSSL doesn't come with certs.
I downloaded a cacert.pem from somewhere online and placed it into the certs folder of the OpenSSL installation but that didn't make much difference either. Still the same `None` error.

On my Linux box, I would expect the websocket connection to succeed and for the code to proceed to `on_open`:

```
fn on_open(&mut self, _: ws::Handshake) -> ws::Result<()> {
...
}
```

---

Has anyone worked through this OpenSSL issue on their Windows development environment?

---

### *UPDATE 0*

As per Cloud's advice, I tried to use VCPKG. Unfortunately it didn't work.

```
PS C:\Users\sam\vcs\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe list
openssl-windows:x64-windows-static                 1.0.2q-2         OpenSSL is an open source project that provides ...
openssl-windows:x86-windows                        1.0.2q-2         OpenSSL is an open source project that provides ...
openssl:x64-windows-static                         0                OpenSSL is an open source project that provides ...
openssl:x86-windows                                0                OpenSSL is an open source project that provides ...
```

Then I set the variables in my powershell window:

```
PS C:\Users\sam\vcs\project> $env:OPENSSL_DIR = 'C:\Users\sam\vcs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static'
PS C:\Users\sam\vcs\project> $env:OPENSSL_STATIC = 'Yes'
PS C:\Users\sam\vcs\project> $env:VCPKGRS_DYNAMIC='1'
```

Then I ran `cargo clean` and then `cargo build` and I still got the same error where my websocket throws the error `None`.

Still no luck here.

Comment: Adding OPENSSL_DIR on the environment variables via UI worked for me

Comment: Same + install Perl for Windows (if not already): https://strawberryperl.com/download/5.32.1.1/strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit.msi

Answer (score 43):

1. clone [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg)
2. open directory where you've cloned vcpkg
3. run `./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`
4. run `./vcpkg.exe install openssl-windows:x64-windows`
5. run `./vcpkg.exe install openssl:x64-windows-static`
6. run `./vcpkg.exe integrate install`
7. run `set VCPKGRS_DYNAMIC=1` (or simply set it as your environment variable)

Comment: From 4 to 6, the command is ./vcpkg.exe command

Comment: I also had to do `$env:OPENSSL_DIR="<vcpkg>\installed\x64-windows-static"`

Comment: I followed to vcpkg README and utilised the above packages to successfully utilise openssl crate in RUST: 
We recommend somewhere like `C:\src\vcpkg` or `C:\dev\vcpkg`,
since otherwise you may run into path issues for some port build systems.
```cmd
> git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
> .\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
```
```cmd
> .\vcpkg\vcpkg install [packages to install]
```
Note: the .exe extension was not used as indicated above 
(Thanks again)

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue. [Older version of the README of rust-openssl has the installation process for the Windows.](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/tree/5948898e54882c0bedd12d87569eb4dbee5bbca7#windows-msvc)

### Precompiled Binaries

Download the precompiled binaries from [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)(non-light version), and install it. After the installation, set the environment variable OPENSSL_DIR to the installation path.

```
set OPENSSL_DIR=path\to\the\installation\dir
```

If you chose the *Copy OpenSSL DLLs to: The OpenSSL binaries (/bin) directory* option during the installation, add that directory to your path as well.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;path\to\the\installation\dir\bin
```

Then, you need to install the root certificate.

### Using vcpkg

Install [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) by following the instructions on the README. After installation, run these commands.

```
vcpkg install openssl:x64-windows
set VCPKG_ROOT=c:\path\to\vcpkg\installation
```

Then, you need to install the root certificate.

### Installing the root certificate

[Download the cacert.pem file](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html). Save it to somewhere (i.e C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\certs\cacert.pem), and add the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable and point it to the file.

```
set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\certs\cacert.pem
```

Comment: Procompiled binaries worked great except that you need to set OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR to C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include and OPENSSL_DIR to the openssl directory as well.  Even with both of those directories added to path it didn't work until they were set.  Also, setting OPENSSL_LIB_DIR to anything was breaking.

Comment: Here are some instructions that helped me, https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/tree/5948898e54882c0bedd12d87569eb4dbee5bbca7#windows-msvc

Answer (score 8):

None of the other answers worked for me but I got it working with vcpkg and static linking. Here is what I did (I was trying to install [wrangler](https://crates.io/crates/wrangler), it worked after following the steps below and running `cargo install wrangler`).

1. Install vcpkg (following the instructions from https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg#quick-start-windows). I ran this in a Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt (`%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"`) but I don't know if this is necessary.

   ```
   cd C:\
   git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
   cd vcpkg
   vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
   ```
2. From the same command prompt, install openssl

   ```
   vcpkg\vcpkg install openssl:x64-windows-static
   ```
3. Install the CA certificates (as described by [Fatih Karan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729715) and the [old README](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/tree/5948898e54882c0bedd12d87569eb4dbee5bbca7#acquiring-root-certificates) of the `rust-openssl` project)

   ```
   mkdir "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\certs"
   curl --remote-name --time-cond "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\certs\cacert.pem" -o "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\certs\cacert.pem" https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem
   ```
4. In a command prompt in your Rust project (or any other directory if you don't have a Rust project and just need to `cargo install` something), set the following environment variables:

   ```
   set OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR=1
   set RUSTFLAGS=-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static
   set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\certs\cacert.pem
   ```

   - `OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR` to `1`: Instruct the `openssl-sys` crate to use a pre-compiled openssl library. If this is not set it will try to compile it and fail (because `perl` is typically not available on Windows).
   - `RUSTFLAGS` to `-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static`: Instruct the Rust compiler (or more precisely the linker invoked by the Rust compiler) to produce a statically linked binary. If this is missing, the `vcpkg` crate (which is [used](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/blob/71b6e3f81f9cf0d1772d00577873cc21ee8f86bf/openssl-sys/build/find_normal.rs#L220) by the `openssl-sys` crate to [find](https://docs.rs/vcpkg/0.2.11/src/vcpkg/lib.rs.html#1156) the pre-compiled openssl library) will use the vcpkg triplet `x64-windows-static-md`. It seems that this triplet does not exist for `openssl`. With this environment variable, `vcpkg` will use the triplet `x64-windows-static` and this worked for me.
   - `SSL_CERT_FILE` to the location of `cacert.pem`: You need the root certificates in this file to make secure connections to servers.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Spent a while on this

Comment: It should be marked as the correct answer for this.

Comment: Set `VCPKG_ROOT` environment variable to your executable location if there is error `vcpkg did not find openssl: Could not find Vcpkg tree: No vcpkg installation found.`.

Answer (score 8):

I just had this issue and none of them worked, but here is what worked for me on Windows 11.

1. Install OpenSSL from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html into `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64`
2. Set all your env variables, for me I set `OPENSSL_CONF` to `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg` and added `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin` to my path.
3. Download the cert, assuming you have wget installed, `wget https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem -o cacert.pem` into `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\certs`
4. Next step is to set up your environment for building openssl run in powershell:

```
 $env:OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR=1
 $env:RUSTFLAGS='-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static'
 $env:SSL_CERT = 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\certs\cacert.pem'
 $env:OPENSSL_DIR = 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64'
```

and run `cargo build`

Answer (score 2):

I do a little tweak from ZZ 5 answer,

so for me to fix it:

1. run on elevated/run as administrator command promt/powershell `git clone git@github.com:microsoft/vcpkg.git d:\dev\vcpkg` it will install the vcpkg to d:\dev. why D:? because on C: it you might get problem with files permissions.
2. then run, `cd d:\dev\vcpkg`
3. run `./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`
4. run `./vcpkg.exe install openssl:x64-windows-release`
5. run `set VCPKGRS_DYNAMIC=1` or set it manually on `edit environment variables` GUI interface, add new variable VCPKGRS_DYNAMIC with value 1
6. run `choco install openssl` (install choco here: https://chocolatey.org/, referrence: https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/1542#issuecomment-954434032)
7. run `winget install -e --id Microsoft.VisualStudio.2022.BuildTools && winget install -e --id Microsoft.VisualStudio.2019.BuildTools`
8. lastly install perl: https://strawberryperl.com/

then, on your RUST project, delete `target` directory. then run `cargo clean && cargo build`

I hope it work for you!

Answer (score 1):

After installing [OpenSSL Win64 .msi latest version](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) just enter the following in terminal:

```
$env:X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_DIR="C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64"
```

(This is the default path where it was installed)

Comment: This worked for me, very straightforward in the end compared to many of the answers

Comment: For future readers, be sure not to install the Light version.

Comment: Now that I have tried the full version, it tells me that the "whatever is the openssl path"\\lib does not contain the required files to either staically or dynamically link openssl. I can see the following structure: in lib folder there is a VC folder, inside that is a x64 folder and inside that are the following 4 folders: "MD", "MDd", "MT", "MTd". What do I do...

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all of it above, seems like not really working right now. The only thing worked for me (maybe combined with the above solution since I've tried everything :D)

```
vcpkg install --triplet=x64-windows-static-md openssl
```

Found here: [link to github](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/1861)

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

in admin:

```
choco install openssl
```

not in admin

```
scoop install perl
```

Answer (score -2):

the cargo build logic for C/C++ libraries is quite simple actually, it just compiles a rust program which searches for include path and libs and then produce some text output and cargo will consume it.

From https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/blob/master/openssl-sys/build/find_normal.rs I can see some `vcpkg` keywords, then I would suggest you simply using [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/) to resolve all your dependencies, and get rid of those env variables.

Comment: Note: you might need static lib, just do `vcpkg install openssl:x64-windows-static`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about vcpkg being the defacto way to install libraries on Windows these days. Unfortunately it didn't quite work. I posted my update in the original post.

Answer (score -2):

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
#Add the current folder into PATH environment variable
vcpkg install openssl-windows:x64-windows
#Switch to the rust project
cargo build
```