# How-To cross platform secret configurations in Rust and Python

Tags: python, rust, configuration

Coming from Python, we are successively adding Rust for new features or replacing Python by Rust for performance reasons.
Our code base has configurations, and some contain secrets.

Currently we use the Python Fernet module (the non-Hazardous Material part of the *cryptography* package) to encrypt and decrypt these secrets.
Although there is a fernet crate for rust, it was not possible to build it on MS Windows. This seems to be a general issue.

So, is there a cross platform (Python/Rust)x(Windows/Linux) way to handle secrets in configurations?

We would settle for the formats supported by the Rust config crate. But the config crate also makes no assumption about secrets, so no help or opinion from there.

Comment: A cursory search hinted to _Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data_, but the impression was that we have to dig deeper than we hope to do.

Comment: What is your hangup on windows? OpenSSL? It looks like it should be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912871/how-to-work-with-openssl-for-rust-within-a-windows-development-environment

Comment: @PitaJ Yes, OpenSSL. I tried using vcpkg to install OpenSSL along one of **many** conflicting recipes, and that one failed after downloading 2GB of packages.

Comment: It appears there's a PR which allows for using rustcrypto instead of openssl. Try specifying it in your dependencies instead: https://github.com/mozilla-services/fernet-rs/pull/65

Comment: Will try that once PR is merged and crate is published.